# Changing the format of my parameter specifically

Tags: date, plsql, format, pentaho, pdi

in my Pentaho Data Integration program I enter a parameter DATE, e.g. 2016-03-15 (or differently, doesn't matter for me). 
Now i want to use this parameter in a Call DB Procedure step, so i need the parameter in the format PL/SQL uses it. The PL/SQL Procedure looks like this: start_test(key_date date, name varchar2)

I have tried to solve it with the select values step but it didn't work so far...

What do i need to change so my parameter works with Call DB Procedure?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you try to solve it with select values, and what format do the PL/SQL proc expect?

Comment: I tried to put the type of the input data do date with select values.
The PL/SQL proc expects the normal date format of PL/SQL I suppose. I am not sure what format that is, I thought: 2016.03.16 06:10:32

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Pentaho so I'm not sure what is the context you'll call a PL/SQL procedure but I hope you'll find the following helpful.

[`date`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref152) is a native Oracle data type. If you have a string presenting a date you have to convert it to a "real" `date` with [`to_date`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132) function:

```
begin
  start_test(
    key_date => to_date('2016-03-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
   ,name     => 'a clever test name'
  );
end;
```

The second `to_date` parameter is a [format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210) that have to match the date string (the first parameter).